# Request->except give me an array instead of a Request object in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, httprequest

`$request->except(['param1'])` gives me an array, I would like to receive a `Request` object..

I'm not sure how to do it...

```
$employee = EmployeeSnap::firstOrNew(['nss' => $request->nss, 'rfc' => $request->rfc]);

        if ($employee->name != null && $employee->name != "") {
            $employee->setData(Input::except(['bankid', 'bankaccount'])); //Input::except(['bankid', 'bankaccount']) gives me array instead of Request
        } else {
            $employee->setData($request);
        }

        $employee->save();
        $id = $employee->employeeid;
        $code = 200;
        $data = 'Success';
        $message = 'Operation successful';
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Option 1**

You can attempt to clone the `Request` object and unset the unneeded variables, as mentioned by @AlexeyMezenin. However, this is only a shallow copy, so any objects related to the original request will be the exact same objects related to the new request. This may or may not cause you issues.

**Option 2**

You can also attempt to generate a new request and replace the input. Something along the lines of:

```
$newRequest = \Illuminate\Http\Request::capture();
$newRequest->replace($request->except(['param1']));
```

However, depending on how you use this new request, it may cause different issues.

**Option 3 (best)**

I think the real solution to your problem is to change the `setData()` method on your `EmployeeSnap` model. `Request` objects really should only be used inside Controllers. The controller should be responsible for interacting with the `Request` to get the data needed, and then it should pass that data to your models as needed.

So, your `setData` method should look like:

```
public function setData(array $request) {
    // use your $request array
}
```

And your controller should look like:

```
$employee = EmployeeSnap::firstOrNew(['nss' => $request->nss, 'rfc' => $request->rfc]);

if ($employee->name != null && $employee->name != "") {
    $employee->setData($request->except(['bankid', 'bankaccount']));
} else {
    $employee->setData($request->all());
}

// rest of code ...
```

This helps separate your concerns, keeps your code a little cleaner, and resolves your issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think I've understood what you want and why (thanks for updated post with code). I guess you will not be able to do this with standard Laravel methods but you could do something like this:

```
$requestCopy = clone $request;
unset($requestCopy->bankid);
unset($requestCopy->bankaccount);
```

So, you're cloning instance of Request class and just remove unsafe properties from it with `unset()`. And then you could use the `$requestCopy` in your code. That's the only way to do it that I can imagine.

This code is just an example, you could do something similar which will work for you.

Comment: I tested it, and it is not working -> must be an instance of Illuminate\\Http\\Request, array given. I thought it was working because PhpStorm doesn't give me the error...